# How to add classifier to dependencies and publish with git branch name?

Tags: scala, sbt

For an sbt/Scala/Play project:

I would like to use the current branch name and add that as a classifier for the dependency resolutions. If it's not a particular branch then I'd like to default with no classifiers.

Also the repo should publish its branch name as classifier.

I.e. If I am on develop branch, all internal dependencies should resolve with classifier `develop` and if on any other branch it should resolve with no classifiers.

Also for `publish`, based on the branch I'd like to add branch name if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.
I ended up using the above approach, i.e. using:
`def branch() = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" !!`
And in the version:
`version := branch + "-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT",`

Pay attention though that you need two exclamation mark and not one (the one return the command returns code).

Now I can use it as resolver in artifactory (and to distinct between different branches).

Answer (score 1):

What about having a `def` to generate `ModuleID`s for your dependencies in `libraryDependencies` that uses `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` under the covers?

Use the following in a `build.sbt` build definition as a gentle start. Use `show libraryDependencies` to print out the dependencies with branch added.

```
def branch() = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD" !

def dependency(g: String, m: String, v: String): ModuleID = {
    g %% m % s"$v-${branch()}"
}

libraryDependencies += dependency("com.typesafe.akka", "akka-actor", "2.3.4")
```

You may also be quite successful with [A GIT plugin for SBT](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-git).

Comment: In Play/Build.scala , how can i get latest SNAPSHOT or latest release version, in gradle world, i just use latest.integration or latest.release. Thanks for helping!

Comment: `latest.integration` as described in [Dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#dependencies) in the official docs of sbt.